# Pull Custom options from list.phtml

Tags: php, custom-options, magento-1.6, php-5.4, phtml

I'm trying to display a "Free Gift" label on the product picture for any product that has the custom options label "Free Gift".

The code I have below works on the actual product page but if I try it on the product list page (list.phmtl) the "Free Gift" label isn't showing up.

I've been told to load my collection but I'm not sure how to do that, won't that also slow my site down if I'm loading my entire collection each time somebody goes on a product list page?

Maybe there's a different solution to my issue?

```
<?php

$theoptions = $_product->getOptions();
foreach($theoptions as $opkey=> $opval)

if(( $_product->getData('has_options')) && ($_product->getTypeID() == 'simple') && ($opval->getTitle() == 'Free Gift')): ?>
   <div class="free_gift_text"><?php echo "Free Gift" ?></div>;
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: In case you haven't noticed, Grid mode and list mode uses different `foreach` loops. Make sure you put your label inside of both loops

Comment: Sorry but I'm new to Magento and PHP. Could you explain what I need to do please?

Comment: I'm sorry, your question is too broad for me to answer. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: My products have a custom option called "Free Gift" and I want my code to read that the product has a free gift option and then echo out some text saying "Free Gift" over the image. 

The code I posted above works on the actual product page, but I also want it to work on the product listing thumbnails. 

This old code I have works on the product listing pages but it displays on all products with ANY custom option, which is not what I want. I'll post it below so you can see.

Comment: <?php if ( $_product->getData('has_options') && ($_product->getTypeID() == 'simple') ): ?>
    <!-- do something --> <div class="free_gift_text"><?php echo "Free Gift" ?></div>; 
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: have you any idea?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have enough time to guide you step by step to solve your problem. If you have a specific question that I can answer, then I might be able to help you. You will have to understand how things work first to ask the right questions.

Comment: @josephdrury did you solve the issue yet?